# Sklearn SVM vs Matlab SVM

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-learn, svm

Problem: I need to train a classifier (in matlab) to classify multiple levels of signal noise.

So i trained a multi class SVM in matlab using the fitcecoc and obtained an accuracy of 92%.

Then i trained a multiclass SVM using sklearn.svm.svc in python, but it seems that however i fiddle with the parameters, i cannot achieve more than 69% accuracy.

30% of the data was held back and used to verify the training. the confusion matrixes can be seen below.

[Matlab confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHFgM.png)

[Python confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4QV2.png)

So if anyone has some experience or suggestions with svm.svc multiclass training and can see a problem in my code, or has a suggestion it would be greatly appreciated.

Python code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#from sklearn import preprocessing

#### SET fitting parameters here
C = 100
gamma = 1e-8

#### SET WEIGHTS HERE
C0_Weight = 1*C
C1_weight = 1*C
C2_weight = 1*C
C3_weight = 1*C
C4_weight = 1*C
#####


X = np.genfromtxt('data/features.csv', delimiter=',')
Y = np.genfromtxt('data/targets.csv', delimiter=',')

print 'feature data is of size: ' + str(X.shape)
print 'target data is of size: ' + str(Y.shape)

# SPLIT X AND Y INTO TRAINING AND TEST SET
test_size = 0.3
X_train, x_test, Y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y,         
... test_size=test_size, random_state=0)

svc = svm.SVC(C=C,kernel='rbf', gamma=gamma, class_weight = {0:C0_Weight, 
... 1:C1_weight, 2:C2_weight, 3:C3_weight, 4:C4_weight},cache_size = 1000)

svc.fit(X_train, Y_train)
scores = cross_val_score(svc, X_train, Y_train, cv=10)
print scores
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))

Out = svc.predict(x_test)

np.savetxt("data/testPredictions.csv", Out, delimiter=",")
np.savetxt("data/testTargets.csv", y_test, delimiter=",")

# calculate accuracy in test data
Hits = 0
HitsOverlap = 0
for idx, val in enumerate(Out):
    Hits += int(y_test[idx]==Out[idx])
    HitsOverlap += int(y_test[idx]==Out[idx]) + int(y_test[idx]==
    ... (Out[idx]-1)) + int(y_test[idx]==(Out[idx]+1))

print "Accuracy in testset: ", Hits*100/(11595*test_size)
print "Accuracy in testset w. overlap: ", HitsOverlap*100/(11595*test_size)
```

to those curious how i got the parameters, they were found with GridSearchCV (and increased the accuracy from 40% to 69)

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much pulling my hair, the answer was found here: http://neerajkumar.org/writings/svm/

when the inputs were scaled with StandardScaler(), svm.svc now produces superior results to matlab!!